# How do I apply DCT to a rgb coloured image?

Tags: image-processing, jpeg

I am  trying to understand the jpeg compression algorithm. If I have a 3-channel color image, do I have to take 3 different Discrete cosine transform (DCT) and quantize for each channel? And after taking inverse DCT, will the result be an jpeg image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a 3-channel color image, do I have to take 3 different Discrete cosine transform (DCT) and quantize for each channel?

Yes, except that the color values are normally converted from RGB to YCbCr first.

Then you have to do run-length compression and Huffman coding on the resulting values. The DCT alone negatively compresses.